Meeting with Boss , HR and Employee Labor Relations Person
My boss has called in a sudden meeting with a title "team update" with HR business partner and labor relationship person. Feel really nervous about the meeting.

What to expect?

How do I be best prepared for the meeting?



Start looking at job boards now to see what is out there.

Is it a team meeting or just you and them?

There is no way for us to know. There is also no point in worrying about it, since there is nothing to do about it.

I’m voting to close this question because we would need a crystal ball and clairvoyance to answer this question.

@AsheraH, it is me, my boss, HR business partner , employee benefits


What to expect?

Hard to say with certainty but it leading candidates are

Significant change in your work environment (role change,
termination, promotion, re-assignment, re-org, PIP, etc.)
Investigation, accusation or disciplinary action (sexual harassment, discrimination, stealing, severe policy violation, etc.)

Think back if you have a clean nose or not? Do you had any conflicts or performance issues in the last year? What did your last performance review say? How is the company or your business unit doing business wise? Were the recent lay offs? Something like this typically doesn't come out of the blue, so maybe there are some past pointers you can use to guess what might be happening.
But yes, chances are it's not going to be a fun meeting.

How do I be best prepared for the meeting?

Assuming it's something profoundly negative.

Be prepared to be calm and collected. Listen a lot and say very little.
Don't argue or get upset. This is not the time for it. Collect data but don't provide any.
Do NOT sign any documents then and there. Do not verbally agree or admit to anything. Ask for time to read and review the documents and to think about your next steps.
Read up on your company policies and local labor law. Know what your rights are and be on the look out for any discrepancy. Note it, but don't comment on it yet unless it gets really confrontational. Then something like "Sorry, I will need my lawyer to review this first" should suffice.
If something is not clear or hard to understand: Ask clarifying question. Questions are the one exception to "say very little".
Make sure you understand if you are entitled to severance and how much this will be. Do NOT sign the severance agreement on the spot. ALWAYS ask for time to review documents before signing them.
Bring pencil and paper and make a visual point of taking notes. Start with writing down names of attendants, time, and place of meeting. This is a "power move", i.e. you show that you are in control of yourself and paying close attention to every detail. If they object to notes, ask "why?". Another good one is "I wasn't aware of a company policy against taking notes at meetings. Can you please point me to the relevant one here? "
Ask for a written transcript of the meeting (which you probably won't get, but just asking is good too). Ask for any proposal, offer or suggestion in writing. Verbal proposals are to easy to twist.
Since you don't know exactly what's going to happen, you should try to think on your feet and adjust as necessary. If in doubt: stall and be non-committal.


Listen a lot and say very little!

You know the answer here - a short notice "team update" with HR and labor relations involved is almost certainly an announcement of layoffs of one form or another.
How to best be prepared: put on your best game face. Don't shoot the messenger. Get your CV up to date.
